# How to save graphs from matplotlib in specific folders (spyder)

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I got a datetime index dataframe with several columns, and I want to plot a graph for each week of a specific column, but I want those graphs to be saved in a specific folder which would be created.
The folder name would be the column name, and the graph name would be 'columnname_week'.

Right now I can save my figs with the good name by using this function :

```
def graph(a):
    for i in range (2,53):
        plt.figure(figsize=[20,20])
        a19=df19[[a]][(df19["week"]==i)]
        plt.plot(a19)
        name=str(a)+"_"+str(i)
        plt.savefig(name)
        
    return

graph('column_name')
```

But I can't find a way to save them in a specific folder by the name of the column.
Also I'm using spyder and it seems that all my plots are being saved in C:\Users\Me instead of the working file where I saved my program, and I can't figure out how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, the reason why it saves to "C:\Users\Me" is because your *name* variable is a relative path then python will save it to the *current work directory (cwd)*.

You can refer to [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to create directories and [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to create a absolute path.

For example,

```
desired_folder = 'D:/some/desired/folder'
os.makedirs(desired_folder)
name=str(a)+"_"+str(i)
full_path = os.path.join(desired_folder, name)
plt.savefig(name)
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it looks like  a good way to do it.
Will I be able to put a variable name on the path?
So if I want for exemple to improve my programm to plot all the columns at the same time and save them in column named folders?

Comment: Do you mean to add more hierarchy in your file paths? You can do makedirs and os.path.join multiple times to generate longer path.